# How do I access and manipulate individual values in a String Array when using a while and for loop

Tags: java

Very new to Java: Trying to learn it.

I created an Array and would like to access individual components of the array.

The first issue I am having is how to I print the array as a batch or the whole array as indicated below? For example: on the last `value` `MyValue4` I added a line break so that when the values are printed, the output will look like this: There has to be a better way to do this?

```
MyValue1
MyValue2
MyValue3
MyValue4

MyValue1
MyValue2
MyValue3
MyValue4
```

The next thing I need to do is, manipulate or replace a value with something else, example: MyValue with MyValx, when the repeat variable is at a certain number or value.
So when the repeat variable reaches 3 change my value to something else and then change back when it reaches 6.

I am familiar with the Replace method, I am just not sure how to put this all together.
I am having trouble with changing just parts of the array with the `while` and `for loop` in the mix.

My Code:

```
public static String[] MyArray() {
    String MyValues[] = { "MyValue1", "MyValue2", "MyValue3", "MyValue4\n" };

    return MyValues;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int repeat = 0;
    while (repeat < 7) {

        for (String lines : MyArray()) {
            System.out.println(lines);
        }

        repeat = repeat + 1;

        if (repeat == 7) {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe to use `for` cycle to be shorter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (String lines : MyArray()) {
        // Changes depended by values.
        if (i > 3) {   
            lines = MyValx;
        }

        System.out.println(lines); // to have `\n` effect
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

And BTW variables will start in lower case and not end with`enter` (`\n`). So use:

```
String myValues[] = {"MyValue1", "MyValue2", "MyValue3", "MyValue4"};
```

instead of:

```
String MyValues[] = { "MyValue1", "MyValue2", "MyValue3", "MyValue4\n" };
```

and add `System.out.println();` after eache inside cycle instead of this:

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the suggestions and example: This is very great.

Answer (score 0):

`MyValues[n] = "value";`

where n is the position in the array.

Comment: So do I manipulate the array in the `for loop`? because I still want to print X number of times but replace the value as I go through the loop.

Comment: Kind of. You might not be able to change he array in the foreach loop you're using but you can do it in a regular for loop:
`for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { array[i] = "new value"; }`

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `System.out.println()` without any argument for printing an empty line instead of inserting new-line characters in your data.

You already know the for-each loop, but consider a count-controlled loop, such as

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

There you can use `i` for accessing your array as well as for deciding for further actions.

Replacing array items based on a number in a string might be a bit trickier. A regular expression will definitely do the job, if you are familiar with that. If not, I can recommend learning this, because it will sure be useful in future situations.

A simpler approach might be using

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("123");  // returns 123 as integer
```

but that only works on strings, which contain pure numbers (positive and negative). It won't work with `abc123`. This will throw an exception.

These are some ideas, you might try out and experiment with. Also use the documentation excessively. ;-)